# Define variables on the right side in a displaymath environment

Tags: math-mode

In

```
\begin{displaymath}
P_1, \dots P_m \leftarrow Q_1, \dots, Q_n (m, n \ge 0)
\end{displaymath}
```

I would like to introduce a bit of spacing before `(m, n \ge 0)`. Maybe put it on the right side? I don't know what would look best or be most standard. But I do know that I need some spacing.
[image: A bit more spacing]

Comment: Have you tried inserting the instructions `\quad` or `\qquad` before `(m, n \ge 0)`?

Comment: Have a look at [Mathmode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) and its section on spacing.

Comment: @Mico: No, but two `\qquad`s to add the spacing looks pretty nice.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I'll look into it if I need to write something more math heavy in the future, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I inserted two `\qquad` thanks to Mico's comment. It looks pretty nice.

```
\begin{displaymath}
P_1, \dots, P_m \leftarrow Q_1, \dots, Q_n \qquad \qquad (m, n \ge 0)
\end{displaymath}
```

Becomes:
[image]

Comment: Mico, not Micro...

Comment: @karlkoeller - thanks. :-) I seem to remember a case of Marco Daniel's first name being rendered as "Macro." I guess this site has it all...

Comment: I'd recommend just one qquad, you will soon run out of space using a double qquad, and using just qquad gives more consistency with more equations

Answer (score 1):

If you want them right-aligned, a quick and dirty way is to abuse the equation-numbering facility available in LaTeX. Use the `\tag` macro (there is also the starred version if you don't want the brackets).